# Type or namespace "XmlNode" could not be found

Tags: c#, xml, dll, .net-assembly

I am getting the error "the type or namespace 'XmlNode' could not be found" even though I am using the following namespaces (including System.Xml):

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Collections.ObjectModel;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Xml;
using System.Xml.Linq;
using Windows.Data.Xml.Dom;
using Windows.Data.Xml.Xsl;
```

The curious thing is, `XmlNodeList` is coming up fine (shows up on IntelliSense).

I have tried all these "using" statements, and have tried changing the Target Platform to see if that would help for some reason (though I don't know why it would).

The app I am building is a UWP Windows App.

I recently updated Visual Studio -- could that be a factor? Does anybody have any insight on this?

Comment: What type of application are you building? For instance, is it a Windows Store app?

Comment: Yes, it is a UWP, sorry about that. Just clarified in the description!

Comment: I'm not sure because I've never done it, just going off what I've read, but I don't think XmlNode is available in UWP. Can you try IXmlNode from the Windows.Data.Xml.Dom namespace?

Comment: UWP uses [tag:.net-core], right?  In that case you may need to nuget https://www.nuget.org/packages/System.Xml.XmlDocument/ to include the XML DOM namespace.

Comment: ^jac - the weird thing is, I have used XmlNode in coding UWP apps previously, so I don't know what happened here. I'm concerned that some settings are off or that the software update had an effect.